# How can i design two different REST API that one serves the list, and other one serves the details?

Tags: node.js, rest

I got into a situation where i need to design REST API that solves two purposes for my CAR company.

```
1) Get the list of Cars.
2) Get the car Details.
```

So, i decided to go like this.

```
 1) GET   /api/engine1/cars  => Provies the list of cars.
 2) GET   /api/engine1/cars/detail (i would send the car number in the payload ).
```

Kindly, let me know if this is the right approach?

Comment: Why not just `GET   /api/engine/cars/1` for the details? It could return only basic info about a car and for more details, you'd do `GET /api/engine/cars/1/details`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev , i would prefer not to use the car number in the get method, but in the payload itself. Hence i have not used like /api/engine/cars/1

Comment: This makes it not RESTful. REST mandates that every resource must be addressable with a URI.

Comment: But if i send the device id in GET method, it is visible outside world right ?

Comment: What makes you think that payload is any less visible?

Comment: :). Let me think and answer your question. I may be with tiny knowledge about it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If we use https, then there is no possibility of looking at payload right?

Comment: Forget about https and payload and security for a second. You asked if this is a good REST api. No, it's not RESTful at all.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure. and Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is somehow opinion based and there is no single correct answer.
But there are some recommendations and documented solutions what worked out well for others.

Check out the [JSON API Specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done. Here is an example using ExpressJS:

```
const app = express();
app.use(parser.json());
app.use('/api/engine1/cars', <car>.router);
```

Inside car router file you can write something like this:

```
router.route('/')
.get((req, res)=>{

res.json(<get the details for all cars here>);
});


router.route('/detail')
.get((req, res)=>{
const carPayload = req.body.payLoad;
res.json(<query  details for all car based on payload number here>);
});
```

Comment: Sumit, Thanks, but my question was about the design of the REST API itself. ;)

Comment: oops, okay. How about GET   /api/engine1/cars/:id in place of second GET